# How to run a FOR loop on a JSONField in Django referring to specific elements

Tags: json, django, django-templates

I have the following JSONField:

```
class Flow(models.Model):
    flow_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    flow_data = JSONField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.flow_title
```

In the `flow_data` JSONField I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "section1": {
        "section_title": "Untitled Section 1",
        "section_description": "Section description 1",
        "field1": {
            "field_name": "Untitled field 1",
            "field_type": "Text",
            "field_value": "This is text value 1"
        },
        "field2": {
            "field_name": "Untitled field 2",
            "field_type": "Text",
            "field_value": "This is text value 2"
        }
    },
    "section2": {
        "section_title": "Untitled Section 1",
        "section_description": "Section description 1",
        "field1": {
            "field_name": "Untitled field 1",
            "field_type": "Text",
            "field_value": "This is text value 1"
        },
        "field2": {
            "field_name": "Untitled field 2",
            "field_type": "Text",
            "field_value": "This is text value 2"
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I know I can pass context in my `views.py` to create the required object:

```
def index(request):
    flow_list = Flow.objects.all()
    return render(request, "index.html", {"flow_list": flow_list})
```

And that I can loop through all of my json objects in the template:

```
{% for object in flow_list %}
    <li>{{ object.id }}>{{ object.flow_data }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

However, if I want to format individual parts of the JSON in the loop like below, how would I do this?

```
{% for object in flow_list %} 
<li>[nth Section]</li>
<li><b>[nth Section Description]</b></li>
<li>[First Field] - [Field Name]</li>
<li>[Second Field] - [Field Name]</li>
etc.   
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iterate over json you can

```
 {% for flow in flow_list % }
      {% for key, value in flow.flow_data.items %}
       <li>{{key}}</li>
          <li><b>[{{key}} {{value.description}}]</b></li>
            {{value.field1.field_name}}
            ...
        {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
```